# How to manage hierarchy wise resource permission?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am building a custom web application, here I have designation feature, each employee will have designation (here is a sample look of my designation https://prnt.sc/nt3ioj)

My requirement is show here:

1. Chairman (from my sample designation) will able to access his child designation's resource
2. Manager will able to access resource of his child designations (Head of IT and Technical Manager)
3. Technical Manager designation will only have his resource access since he dose not have any child designation
4. and so on....

I need a optimized solution for this problem.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario on one of my projects.  What I did was to create a Laravel Middelware that gave me the ids of me and my children using a recursive function.

Here is the code for my Middleware file

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Auth;
use Closure;
use App\Models\Nomina\Empleado;

class Subordinados
{
    protected $subordinates = [];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $this->recursiveSearch(Auth::id());
        $request->request->add(['subordinados' => $this->subordinates]);
        return $next($request);
    }

    private function recursiveSearch($aUserId)
    {
        $empleados = Empleado::where('superiorid', $aUserId)->select('empleadoid')->get();
        foreach ($empleados as $empleado) {
            $this->recursiveSearch($empleado->empleadoid);
            $this->subordinates[] = $empleado->empleadoid;
        }
    }
}
```

When adding this middleware to a route, I would be able to do something like this on my controller:

```
function index(Request $request) {
    Empleado::whereIn('empleadoid', $request->subordinados);
}
```

which will only show me the ids of me and my children.

Hope it helps!